# htaccess prevent redirect in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the following code in the parent directory to redirect all non-existing directories to a landing page.  The issue is that I still wish for 404 errors to occur in sub-directories such as admin,clients,images.... Is it possible to apply the following to only directories in the parent directory and not follow through to subdirectories?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#Redirect For variables.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ landing.php?local=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/? landing.php?local=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#Redirect For variables.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ landing.php?local=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`^([^/]+)/?$` will match a URI in root dir only. There is no need for 2nd rule.

Comment: This just combined the two above it does not fix the issue. When I try /admin/test it does not give a 404 error

Comment: Does `/admin/test` open `/landing.php` or some other content?

Comment: It opens /landing.php

Comment: `^([^/]+)/?$` cannot match `/admin/test` unless you have some other rule or some other .htaccess

Comment: To test, just make sure to have only this code in your root .htaccess

Comment: It is only in the parent directory. There are no other htaccess files.  This is the only code I am using in the document as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67158/discussion-between-anubhava-and-james).

Comment: I am sorry I was away for a few hours. I will be in chat for a while.

Comment: I just got back online. What URL did you enter in browser? Do one more test. Create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://domain.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value?

Comment: I put 192.168.0.125/admin/test to test the file.  The document root is as follows /home/user/public_html

Comment: ok change `landing.php` in above rule to `info.php` and then re-visit `http://192.168.0.125/admin/test`. From the browser output tell me what you see as `$_GET['local']` value

Comment: 404.shtml but it is redirecting to info.php rather than the default 404 page in sub directories.  Would it make a difference it I set the default error page within the subdirectories? I will be in chat